# How to load a bitmap for an android game?

Tags: java, android

i been working on a game with no bitmaps or anything, I'm using rectangles as objects and changing their color for their purpose like a red rectangles for player and gray rectangles for walls. My question is what is the right way to replace the rectangles with bitmaps/images?

I know to load Bitmaps you can just do this :

```
Bitmap randomBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
com.example.android4gametest.R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Should i load all my Bitmaps and pass them to their Classes or should i load the bitmap inside their class instead of passing it ? and how would i do that because i cannot use the BitmapFactory because i have no access to the getResources()! or should i load my bitmaps/images from my assets folder which i know i wont have the same "tools" you can say to mess with the bitmap.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Game theGame;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(new Game(this));
}
}
```

The Game Panel
    public class Game extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

```
GameThread _thread;

public Game(Context context) {
    super(context);

    getHolder().addCallback(this);

    setFocusable(true);

    _thread = new GameThread(getHolder(), this);


}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    _thread.setRunning(true);
    _thread.start();

}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Log.d("OnDraw", "it is Drawing");
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
}

public void update() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
}
}
```

GameLoop Nothing here

```
    public class GameThread extends Thread{
/*FPS Code*/
private final static int MAX_FPS = 30;
private static final int FRAME_PERIOD = 1000/MAX_FPS;




protected SurfaceHolder holder;
protected Game game;
private boolean isRunning = false;

public GameThread(SurfaceHolder _holder, Game _game) {
    this.holder = _holder;
    this.game = _game;
}



/**
 * Returns True if the game is still running and False if the game is over
 * @return
 */
public boolean isRunning() {
    return isRunning;
}
/**
 * Set to true for the game loop to start 
 * @param isRunning
 */
public void setRunning(boolean isRunning) {
    this.isRunning = isRunning;
}


@Override
public void run() {
    Canvas c;
    Log.d("Pallyways", "Starting game Loop");

    long beingTime;
    long timeDiff;
    int sleepTime;
    int framesSkipped;

    sleepTime = 0;

    while(isRunning){
        c = null;
        try{

            c = holder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized(holder){
                beingTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                framesSkipped = 0;
                game.update();//Update
                game.onDraw(c);//Redraw

                timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beingTime ;
                sleepTime = (int) (FRAME_PERIOD - timeDiff);

                if(sleepTime>0){
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);} 
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();}
                    finally{}
                }

                while(sleepTime<0 && framesSkipped < 5){
                    game.update();

                    sleepTime+= FRAME_PERIOD;
                    framesSkipped++;
                }

            }
        }finally{if(c!=null){
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Hero Class I have not started but i would like to know how to load a bitmap on a class that is on a different Package

```
package com.example.android4gametest.Actors;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

import com.example.android4gametest.R;

public class Hero {
//getContext() gives me an error and that is because it does not have a reference

private Bitmap hero = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(),
R.drawable.ic_launcher);
public Hero(){

}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the sizes/number of bitmaps, it may be fine to load them in the constructor of your Game class. Be aware though, if you're loading too many/too big bitmaps into memory at once, you may run into some OOM errors or a lag in when your first draw call gets made. You have to be sure you're nulling, recycling your bitmaps efficiently when you no longer need them. Struggled with this issue with my first game

Comment: ahh i will be doing some research about recycling bitmaps! and no as in for now my game online needs 4 bitmaps hero, walls, goal, and object that can be moved by the player

Answer (score 1):

Do not load the `Bitmap` in your game object's constructors.  If any of those `Bitmaps` would be used by multiple objects (i.e. an enemy class), then if you loaded them in your object's constructors you would have multiple copies of the `Bitmap` in memory.  This could lead to an `OutOfMemoryException`.  Instead load your `Bitmap` outside of your constructors (in your game thread or game panel) and then pass the `Bitmap` objects to the constructors or setters and set your private `Bitmaps` that way.  You'll only have to keep a limited number of `Bitmaps` in memory.

You may also want to consider a loading "screen" which displays a progress bar or spinner while you load those `Bitmaps`.

Comment: my updated Hero class takes `Context` as a parameter and then in the Hero constructor i asaing the bitmap to the hero class `public Hero(context){ bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher}` is this not the right way to do it? can you provide me and example for better understanding

Comment: That's okay for an object like your Hero class, but if you have enemies or powerups that could be repeated, then you would want to call the decodeResource method once on your resource in your managing class or thread class and pass it like this in a constructor: Powerup(Bitmap health).  Sorry if this isn't helping.

Answer (score 0):

Where you load is not important. I think your main issue is accessing the resources. In a view, you can call:

```
getContext().getResources()
```

Edit:

So in the method signature of the constructor of Hero add Context as a parameter:

```
public Hero(Context context){
  private Bitmap hero = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
}
```

Comment: would i have to pass to context to my class in order to load it by using the bitmap? so lets say my class hero constructor would be something like `Hero(Context)`

Comment: Aha my bad, thought your class extended View. Yup, that would also work. Just don't keep a global reference to the Context or keep it in a WeakReference

Comment: i know that can work but is it the right way ? as in efficient way to do it ?

Comment: I can't see a reason why not. Just remember to recycle your bitmaps when you're done with them / on rotate etc.

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT! use dynamic objects.. I mean Do not create dynamic objects in a game at all, these will trigger the GC and make everything stutter when it's running whenever it wants. You must take control over everything yourself and use static/final "objects" and arrays on the obstacles and enemies. The objects will be loaded on to the heap at startup, which means that you will have them loaded until the app is shut down. Therefore you must find the balance between what to have in these static objects and not, but it's easy when you have found it.

The bitmaps should be loaded outside these static non-dynamic objects, the objects should only do the calculations.

And never use any unnessesary calculations, loops or Thread.sleep in between your
c = holder.lockCanvas(); and holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c); like you're doing in your code.
This can and will finally make the game flicker.

Regards,
Me